# Remove/ignore everything except characters in a Cstring

Tags: c++, c-strings

I am trying to get read in some text about 100 char long or less and then strip it of spaces, digits, special char, etc.. I was thinking about ways to go about doing this but I think I must have forgotten most of what I know about cstrings and such. I was originally trying to just take in basic characters and copy them into a new string but 1. I couldn't figure out how to write it so my compiler doesn't hate me and 2. I'm pretty sure I don't want the new, stripped string to have blanks in it (I'm pretty sure my code so far would cause that to happen, if it even worked).

```
char * userText="";
char * justCharTxt;

cout << "Enter text: " << endl;
cin.getline(userText, STRING_SIZE);
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(userText); i++){
    if (((userText[i] >= 'a') && (userText[i] <= 'z')) ||
        ((userText[i] >= 'A') && (userText[i] <= 'Z')))
        *justCharTxt = userTxt[i];
}
```

Some guidance on this issue would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: You haven't allocated any storage for `userText`. Try `char userText[STRING_SIZE]`.

Comment: Since nobody has pointed it out `char * userText="";` is **spectacularly bad**. you are assigning a pointer to the first element of a constant array to a non-const pointer variable. Attempting to write to that array (i.e. with `getline`) will result in undefined behavior. C++03 allows the assignment to non-const but it has been deprecated as of C++11. Also consider the suggestion of using `std::string`, it's the best advice you'll get all day.

Comment: Sweet, thanks guyz. I had been trying to remember how to set these things up and this was my best guess. Its been a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you need to init your strings, i.e., reserve a buffer
2. you need to increment the dest pointer.

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> using namespace std;
> ```

```
int main(){
int const STRING_SIZE=20;
char userText[STRING_SIZE*2]="";
char justCharTxt[STRING_SIZE]="";
char * txtPt = justCharTxt;
cout << "Enter text: " << endl;
cin.getline(userText, STRING_SIZE);
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(userText); i++){
    if (((userText[i] >= 'a') && (userText[i] <= 'z')) ||
        ((userText[i] >= 'A') && (userText[i] <= 'Z')))
        *(txtPt++)= userText[i];
}
cout << justCharTxt << endl;
return 0;
}
```

> ```
> $ clang++ justit.cpp
> $ ./a.out
> Enter text:
> ab123 a
> aba
> ```

Comment: Beautiful, that is a lot smoother than what I was thinking.

Comment: The answer is basically C coding.  There is very little C++ in the answer.

Comment: Awesome, solid point. I'm planning on using a lot more c++ for the rest of what I'm doing.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a `std::string`, no need to fiddle around with `char` arrays or pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::string line;
  getline(std::cin, line);

  line.erase(
    std::remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(),
      [](char c) {return !isalpha(c, std::locale());}),
    line.end()
  );

  std::cout << line << '\n';
}
```

Comment: While I appreciate the advice, I was should have included that I'm trying to stick with cstrings, otherwise, you got a good idea there.

Comment: `I'm trying to stick with cstrings`  Seriously, I'm beginning to wonder if C++ is the only language where solutions aren't solutions.  Why do so many not use what C++ has to offer?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I reckon a) Homework from teachers who learned C++ 20 years ago and b) "Because it's faster" are the most common reasons, I know I was once guilty of b)...

Comment: I wouldn't feel like a real man if I couldn't remember how to use Cstrings lol

Comment: @entimaniac Fair enough, although in that case your question is more C than C++.

Comment: @entimaniac - The issue with using C-strings like this is the big picture -- I can tell right away that the above answer given by user657267 works correctly without me having to compile and run it.  That's the beauty of using higher-level constructs.  The other answer given that uses C coding requires me to read every line of the loop, check if the if() statement does what it's supposed to do, no silly typos that would compile OK but at runtime produce bad results, etc.

Comment: I definitely understand that. If this wasn't just messing around, I would being using so many string class strings, we wouldn't know what to do with them.

Comment: Why do you use that version of isalpha?

Comment: @MattMcNabb To make sure that the characters are compared against the current global `ctype` facet. Obviously it won't make a difference in the code above as compiled, but as part of a larger program it might.

Comment: isn't that the default?

Comment: @MattMcNabb sorry I edited my comment too late, have another look.

Answer (score 0):

Your char arrays do not have enough memory, and they are const.
char userText[STRING_SIZE];